# Difference of the solution at two time instants

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality, dynamical-systems

Consider a nonlinear nonautonomous differential equation of the type
$$ \dot{z}(t) = f(t,z(t)) $$
with $f:\mathbb{R}^+\times\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ being a Lipschitz function. Is there some simple way to control the difference, in norm, of the solution at two time instants? For example given an $h>0$ and a $T>0$, what can we say about $\|z(T+h)-z(T)\|$, where by $\|\cdot\|$ we refer to the Euclidean norm?

My approach was quite classical, i.e. to study $\frac{d}{dt}(\|z(T)-z(T+h)\|^2)$ and proceed aiming to use some Gronwall type inequality, however, I did not get something interesting.